# Android Playlists Content not found

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

```
public static ArrayList<Song> getPlaylistcontent(Context context,
        long playlistID) {
    ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

    final String idString = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID;
    final String dataString = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA;

    String[] projection = new String[] { idString, dataString };
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external",
            playlistID);

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
            null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            final String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(idString));
            final String path = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(dataString));

            Song song = getSong(context, path);
            if (song != null) {
                songs.add(song);
                Log.d("MyTAG", song.getName());
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return songs;
}

public static ArrayList<Playlist> getAllPlaylists(Context context) {
    return helper_getPlaylists(context, null);
}

private static ArrayList<Playlist> helper_getPlaylists(Context context,
        String selection) {

    ArrayList<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();

    final String idString = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID;
    final String nameString = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME;

    Uri externalUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String projection[] = new String[] { idString, nameString };

    // sort by date added
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_ADDED;

    Cursor audioCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(externalUri,
            projection, selection, null, sortOrder);

    if (audioCursor != null && audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            final String id = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(idString));
            final String name = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(nameString));

            Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
            playlist.setName(name);
            playlist.setID(id);
            playlists.add(playlist);

        } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return playlists;
}
```

These are 2 (3) methods I use to get the playlist content. Well, they should return the playlist content but it doesn't. The method `getSong()` works 100% and is not the problem. I use it few thousand times in another part of my program and it is fast and also reviewed on code-review.

I call `getAllPlaylists()` in the main activity, display these playlists in a `ListView` and when I click on one item, I will start a new activity which should display the items of that playlist. So I pass the clicked playlist's ID through an intent and use it in the new activity (works and I do get the correct ID's).

```
//MainActivity
Arraylist<Playlist> playlists = MediaManager.getAllPlaylists( this );

//New Activity
long playlistID = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("playlist_id"); //works. 

//in an asynctask in new activity
Arraylist<Song> playlistContent = MediaManager.getPlaylistContent( this, playlistID ); //is empty
```

This is driving me crazy! What did I do wrong?

Comment: I get the correct uri, but the cursor says there are 0 items although there MUST be some value. I even added a song to the playlist with the default google player

Comment: Did you resolve this? I do not quite understand your problem, perhaps you can restate the issue ?

Comment: @Theo No, I didn't. I use a sqlite databsae now to store my playlist content. Maybe I can describe my problem better if you tell me what you have understood / not understood from my question.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, the intent to get playlist details works, you get the _ids but you do not get the songs. Remember that the _id is the id of the line of each playlist item, NOT the audio_id. I struggled with this for a while. Perhaps this was your issue.
This is how I resolved it:

```
public Cursor getPlaylistTracks(Context context, Long playlist_id) {
    Uri newuri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(
            "external", playlist_id);
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID;
    String audio_id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID;
    String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST;
    String album = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM;
    String album_id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM_ID;
    String title = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE;
    String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DURATION;
    String location = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA;
    String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.COMPOSER;
    String playorder = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER;
    String date_modified = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATE_MODIFIED;
    String[] columns = { _id, audio_id, artist, album_id,album, title, duration,
            location, date_modified, playorder, composer };
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(newuri, columns, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: I will check it out soon. I'm very busy at the moment and I don't know when I can test this code. Thanks, though.